# How to define Class type property using get() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-interop

How to define a property using get() in **Kotlin** which returns a class, I was trying below, but it's not compiling

```
val targetActivity: Class<?>
    get() = MyActivity.class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`Class References`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references)

> The most basic reflection feature is getting the runtime reference to a Kotlin class. To obtain the reference to a statically known Kotlin class, you can use the class

literal syntax:

```
val c = MyClass::class
```

or this use **`Class<*>`** instead of **`Class<?>`**

```
val targetActivity: Class<*>
get() = MyActivity::class
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that in Kotlin you have to use [*star projection*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections), the question mark `<?>` won’t work; also use [class references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) like this:

```
val targetActivity: KClass<*>
    get() = MyActivity::class
```

If you want to have a Java `Class`, use the `.java` property: `MyActivity::class.java`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use .java after getting a Kotlin KClass to return a Java Class

```
val targetActivity: Class<*>
  get() = MyActivity::class.java
```

Or, if you want to be more specific about the return type

```
val targetActivity: Class<MyActivity>
  get() = MyActivity::class.java
```